# Replacing isPresent with ifPresent and orElse

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda, option-type

I have the following logic in my method where I check for the value of an optional parameter, and depending on that I build another object.

```
AtomicReference<Employee> employeeValue = null;
    questions.forEach(question -> {
        if(question.isBoolean().isPresent()) {
            employeeValue.set(Employee.builder()
                    .withBooleanValue(Boolean.valueOf(question.value()))
                    .build());
        } else {
            employeeValue.set(Employee.builder()
                    .withStringValue(question.value())
                    .build());
        }
        Record record = Record.builder()
                .withId(question.id())
                .withValue(employeeValue.get())
                .build();
        answers.add(record);
    });
```

How can I replace the above with ifPresent and orElse? I'm using Java 8 and therefore ifPresentOrElse method is not available. If I am to use ifPresent and orElse separately with anonymous inner function, how do I go about it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neither need `isPresent()` nor `ifPresent()`. You don’t need `peek()` (as in the other answer) nor an `AtomicReference` (as in the question). I believe that this does it:

```
    questions.forEach(question -> {
        Employee empl = question.isBoolean()
                .map(b -> Employee.builder()
                        .withBooleanValue(Boolean.valueOf(question.value()))
                        .build())
                .orElseGet(() -> Employee.builder()
                        .withStringValue(question.value())
                        .build());
        Record record = Record.builder()
                .withId(question.id())
                .withValue(empl)
                .build();
        answers.add(record);
    });
```

You can probably apply this idea inside the stream from the other answer if you want. Rather than using `Stream.forEach()` I’d prefer to collect into a collection like a list and then use `answers.addAll()`.

Comment: That's an excellent take! thanks so much for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

You can stream through `questions` and use `peek` and `map`-`orElse` construction to achieve the same result:

```
questions.stream()
    .peek(question -> {
            Employee employee = question.isBoolean()
                .map(b -> Employee.builder().withBooleanValue(Boolean.valueOf(question.value())).build())
                .orElse(Employee.builder().withStringValue(question.value()).build());
            employeeValue.set(employee);
        }
    )
    .map(question -> Record.builder().withId(question.id()).withValue(employeeValue.get()).build())
    .forEach(answers.add(answer)); // did you mean 'record'?
```

But to be honest it does not change a lot - your implementation looks maybe less "java eightish" but is fine :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. However I am getting 'Cannot resolve method orElseGet (<lambda expression>). Is that line missing something?

Comment: Yeah you're right - in java8 you need to use `map`-`orElse` construction - I've updated answer

Comment: Yes indeed, the problem is that `orElseGet` is `Optional`'s method thus it's not available after calling `ifPresent` anymore